# Anybody used logback in a Mule Application?

Tags: mule, logback

has anyone been able to use logback for their application deployed in Mule. 
I have got a file appender configured and got logback.xml in my classpath. However this doesn't seem to get picked up.

Kindly note Mule is stil probably using it's own default log4j implementation as I see mule.log does get some logging though not the ones I am attempting to log - which makes me feel my explicit log events are getting lost alltogether. 
Mule by default uses log4j but guess we can override that?
Some documentation here but not too helpful
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE3USER/Configuring+Logging

What I want is use Logback just for my application without making changes to Mule System level jars and config.

FYI; I am trying to use the following in logback.xml

```
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>D:\logs\mule\myauto.log</file>
        <encoder>
              <pattern>%d [%p] <%c> %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="asyncFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </appender>

  <logger name="automationlogger" level="INFO">

        <appender-ref ref="asyncFileAppender" />
  </logger>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with mule, but you can always use slf4j + logback, this would enable you to redirect logging calls made to log4j with the help of slf4j's [log4j bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html).

Comment: I will have a quick look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The per-app logging is hardcoded to slf4j/log4j as mule-module-logging overrides some slf4j classes that the mule team had to change in order to make it work.

If you take a look at the [mule-module-logging pom](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/inspect-pom/org/mule/modules/mule-module-logging/3.2.1/mule-module-logging-3.2.1.pom) you can see what classes are shaded and why this won't allow you to use logback unless hacking directly the mule code.

Comment: Thanks. I guess Mule has really deep rooted dependency on log4j. I treid replacing the mule-logging-module and the log4j jars/configs and the wrapper simply refused to start the application. Even running standalone didnt help. In Mule website they did mention it is possible    http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Configuring+Logging    but not much details. I guess I will have to give logback a miss inside Mule unless they start supporting it out of the box :(

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to replace the log4j jar files with logback and didn't work. The wrapper uses the log4j for logging and hence u need to have log4j jars in /lib/boot dir. If I add logback jars with out removing the log4j jars u get below warnings ..

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/dev/mule-standalone-3.3.1/lib/boot/logback-classic-1.0.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/dev/mule-standalone-3.3.1/lib/boot/mule-module-logging-3.3.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

Now to remove mule logging module and add jcl-over-slf4j. Server starts and picks up logback.xml in config folder. But the mule application specific logging is gone.

End of the day, this is what I have done.

Remove : mule-module-logging-3.3.1

Add : logback-classic-1.0.9, logback-core-1.0.9, jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.2, log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.2

Comment: Hi sorry can you elaborate a bit more? So currently are you getting Mule server logs as well logs done by your own applications?